# ERROR: Too many calls to session.endDialog() with MS botframework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have having a play with this to create one for a fictional utility company, and looking at using LUIS to interpret my response and pass information back. I am happy with the LUIS side of it. If I ask "when did my gas contract start", I get the following returned:

```
{
  "query": "when did my gas contract start",
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "StartDate",
      "score": 0.9994442
    }
  ],
 "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "gas",
      "type": "ProductType",
      "startIndex": 12,
      "endIndex": 14,
      "score": 0.998134553
    }
  ]
}
```

So an intent of "startdate" and a entity "gas".

Inside my app.js, I have the following line:

```
dialog.on('StartDate', [askProduct, answerQuestion('StartDate', prompts.answerStartDate)]);
```

I get the  error in the title when (I think) doing the waterfall section.

I am not sure if it is something to do with my generic waterfall answer, which I shamelessly stole from the basics-multiTurn example. So my answer code is as follows:

```
function answerQuestion(field, answerTemplate) {
    return function (session, results) {
        // Check to see if we have a product. The user can cancel picking a product so IPromptResult.response
        // can be null. 
        if (results.response) {
            // Save product for multi-turn case and compose answer            
            var Product = session.dialogData.Product = results.response;
            var answer = { Product: Product.entity, value: data[Product.entity][field] };
            session.send(answerTemplate, answer);
        } else {
            session.send(prompts.cancel);
        }
    };
}
```

The data in my app.js is

```
var data = {
  'Gas': {
      StartDate: 'Mar 10, 2016',
      NextInvoiceDate: 'June 13, 2016',
      LastInvoiceDate: 'May 13, 2016',
      LastAmount: '£23.56',
      NextAmount: '£26.32',
      description: 'You gas bill is based around the units of gas you have used in the past billing period, plus a standing charge. You next bill is an extrapolation if your current usage data for the period, and also based on your usage history.',
      website: 'http://www.blah.com'
  },

  'Electricity': {
      StartDate: 'Mar 10, 2016',
      NextInvoiceDate: 'June 13, 2016',
      LastInvoiceDate: 'May 13, 2016',
      LastAmount: '£27.35',
      NextAmount: '£29.72',
      description: 'You electricity bill is based around the units of gas you have used in the past billing period, plus a standing charge. You next bill is an extrapolation if your current usage data for the period, and also based on your usage history.',
      website: 'http://www.blah.com'
  },
};
```

My prompts file contains:

```
answerStartDate: "Your %(Product) Product started on %(value).",
```

Any ideas?

Comment: None of your posted code shows any references to `session.endDialog()`. Where is the code that is triggering the error "ERROR: Too many calls to session.endDialog()"? Can you provide an example I can use to reproduce this error?